# Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to look at the available ports before to connecting. I have seen tons of explanations, but none of them are working.

This is my code

```
public int portxt = 27001;
public void GetOpenPort()
    {
        using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {

            try
            {
                tcpClient.Connect("192.168.1.32", portxt);
                MessageBox.Show("Port open");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Port closed");
                randomport();


                txtPort.Text = portxt;
            }
        }
    }
    public void randomport()
    {
        Random portx = new Random();
        int month = portx.Next(0, 65535);
    }
```

i finally discovery how to make it work
This is the final code

```
public void GetOpenPort()
    {
        using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {

            try
            {
                tcpClient.Connect("192.168.1.32", portxt);
                MessageBox.Show("Port open");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Port closed");
                randomport();
                //txtPort.Text = portxt.ToString();


            }
        }
    }
    public void randomport()
    {
        Random portx = new Random();
        int month = portx.Next(27001, 65535);
        txtPort.Text = portx.Next(Convert.ToInt32("0"), Convert.ToInt32("65535")).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: And *where* in your code does the error occur?

Comment: @marc_s hi hello tanks for the replay here is the error txtPort.Text = portxt;

Comment: Try this txtPort.Text =portxt.ToString();

Comment: @marc_s hi tanks its solved the problem but now wen i try to call the random function to generate a new port in case the port is close random generate a new port and then assign to the txtport.text but its return System.Random the random function is public void randomport()
        {
            Random portx = new Random();
            int month = portx.Next(0, 65535);
            txtPort.Text = portx.ToString();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *convert* your `int` to a string (using the `.ToString()` method) so that it can be displayed on a textbox:

```
public int portxt = 27001;

public void GetOpenPort()
{
    using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect("192.168.1.32", portxt);
            MessageBox.Show("Port open");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Port closed");
            randomport();

            txtPort.Text = portxt.ToString();  // convert your INT to a string!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally get it to work i will share the code for all of you.

Comment: @SilviaFonseca: please **DO NOT** put code and samples into comments - you can't properly format this. Please instead **update your question** and provide additional code - or ask a new question instead